# Partial web form request, AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jquery

I'm not sure how to ask this.

I have a HTML form that has several fields, including `user id`, which maps to a real name. I have jQuery validation of the form working.

Right now, I have to submit the POST request, to show the user's real name.

example: It should show "john doe" if the user types "3", before without clicking submit.

```
ID input: [3] ( john doe )
```

Do I use jQuery to retrieve this information? Do I also set up a new page, that has a response to a POST request, that returns 'john doe' as XML / JSON or something along those lines?

note: Using python's `Flask`. Maybe I should use [Flask-Sijax](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Sijax/) ?

Answer (score 0):

The Flask documentation has [a good example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/) using jquery to fetch a value from the server without posting the whole page.

If you wanted it to fire as a user types the number (rather then hitting a button in the example) you could use the [.keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event in jQuery instead of the .bind/click event shown the example.